# In sqlalchemy, is there a way to sort so that empty cells are at the end irrespective or sort order?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a pretty standard setup and want to sort by a column:

`someselect.order_by(asc(table1.mycol))`

However, I want rows with `''` or `NULL` for `mycol` to appear at the end of the results. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has a `NULLS LAST` modifier for `ORDER BY` expressions:

```
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.nullslast(column)
```

See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.nullslast

You can use it like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import nullslast

# ...

someselect.order_by(nullslast(table1.mycol.asc()))
```

There is also `nullsfirst`.

Comment: Note this doesn't seem to work in older MySQL versions. For me on 5.7 it generates a syntax error

Comment: `nullsfirst` and `nullslast` have been renamed to `nulls_first` and `nulls_last` in 1.4+, although as of 2.0 the old names still work.

Answer (score 6):

On databases that support `NULLS LAST`, you can sort `NULL`s at the end by doing

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY mycol ASC NULLS LAST;
```

You need to convert `''` to `NULL`s so you can do this (which I recommend doing anyway), either in the data or as part of the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY (CASE mycol WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE mycol END) ASC NULLS LAST;
```

Alternatively, a more portable approach is

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY (CASE WHEN mycol IS NULL OR mycol = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, mycol;
```

To write this in SQLAlchemy:

```
.order_by(case([(or_(tabel1.mycol.is_(None), table1.mycol == ""), 1)],
               else_=0), table1.mycol)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import nulls_last

result = session.query(self.model).order_by(nulls_last(model.column.desc())
```

Visit https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.nulls_last