# Is there a way to get NULLS LAST like functionality with SQLAlchemy and MariaDB?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mariadb

Take this trivial table example:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

I want to use SQLAlchemy to fetch all enabled objects, smallest number first (aka highest priority), with nulls last.

According to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774047/13045149) I should be able to do this:

```
session.query(Example).filter_by(enabled=True).order_by(Example.priority.asc().nullslast())
```

But that produces this exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULLS LAST' at line 3")
```

The generated SQL ends like this, which appears invalid:

```
WHERE example.enabled = true ORDER BY example.priority DESC NULLS LAST
```

Fiddling around in the MariaDB console, both of these queries get me what I want:

```
SELECT id FROM example WHERE enabled = TRUE ORDER BY priority IS NULL, priority ASC;
SELECT id FROM patches WHERE enabled = TRUE ORDER BY -priority DESC;
```

But I can't work out how to actually make SQLAlchemy generate me either of these looking at the docs.

This gets close but still causes an SQL error:

```
session.query(Example).filter_by(enabled=True).order_by(Example.priority.nullslast(), Example.priority.asc())
... WHERE example.enabled = true ORDER BY example.priority NULLS LAST, example.priority ASC
```

If I could replace the `NULLS LAST` with `IS NULL` it would work, but `.isnull()` isn't a thing.

This doesn't cause an SQL error but still puts the nulls first:

```
session.query(Example).filter_by(enabled=True).order_by(Example.priority.isnot(None), Example.priority.asc())
```

No idea what to try next...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the sqlalchemy [`.is_()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.is_) operator:

```py
session.query(Example).filter_by(enabled=True).order_by(Example.priority.is_(None),
                                                        Example.priority.asc())
```

Alternatively you could use `Example.priority == None`.

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks!